# Xcode found C++ headers from framework, now a build later it can't

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I'm porting a C++ Windows program that uses openCV to Mac. I installed the openCV framework, fixed a few build issues, then ran it. Worked pretty well. Then I changed a line of source code (adding a debugging std::cout), rebuilt, and now get these build errors:

```
(!) 'opencv2/highgui.hpp' file not found
(!) Did not find header 'highgui.hpp' in framework 'opencv2' (loaded from '/Users/bill/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/spot-engine-motile-gwtigogqvbxktiabuwebnnwzxgzg/Build/Products/Debug')
```

I undid my change, but these errors persist. I tried removing the framework and dragging it back in again (it is installed in /Library/Frameworks), several times, but always the same error. I found people with similar errors who fixed it by setting the "Search Paths/Framework Search Paths" correctly, but mine was already set to "/Library/Frameworks". Anybody else know what I might want to look at? It's driving me crazy, I actually had the program running for 15 minutes, now it's gone and I can't figure out how to get it working again.

Comment: Yeah, look at the build log. Find the error in the left hand pane thinger, then right click "Reveal in Log"~. That'll show you the complete command that failed, including arguments and environment variables. Those arguments should include the OpenCV header search path.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the build log. I should add I'm also new to XCode (I've done C++ in the past, but all my Mac development before this was Java or Python). The build log shows no "-I/Library/Frameworks/opencv2" (the text opencv2 appears nowhere on the command line), but how to fix that?

Comment: That I don't know. I would think that adding a framework would set the header search paths. Is there any evidence of that in the compiler arguments?

Comment: No, I don't see anything on the command line that indicates it is using the framework. I'm also puzzled, it knows that "opencv2" should come from the framework according to the 2nd error message, but the "loaded from..." path is weird, it isn't to the actual framework at all.

Comment: I honestly don't know, but maybe adding it as a framework only configure it for linking? That sounds too crazy to be true. You could experiment with configuring the header search path manually via 'select project node in project browser', select build target, select 'Build Settings' tab, and mucking in the 'Search Paths' section

Comment: I finally gave up. I took out the framework that I downloaded from the opencv site, then used brew to install it separately and added explicit links to the brew-based include files and library files. This is much clumsier, the framework should do the job much more elegantly, but I've been trying to get it to work for a day now and finally gave up.

Comment: Programmmmmming